# Volley network parallel requests

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using volley to download byte array data from a cloud which I have access to.

My implementation sometimes performs about 200 request in a single for loop to get 200 array (the average size of the file is 700 KB, and a few files goes up to 1 MB) and store them in the device.

My problem is that the CPU usage goes wild, although I know that volley has a request queue and it only handles 4 request in the same time as a default value of DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 4.

Does anyone have an idea why this overhead is happening, is it because of the cache of volley or the method writing the files on the device?

This is the code I'm using for saving a file to the device

```
private void writeAudioFile(byte[] arrayByte, String name) throws 
                  IOException {
     FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(name);
     outputStream.write(arrayByte);
     outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Really not sure if that's what you want... Can't you just do 1 request in order to get all the arrays?

Comment: how about using retrofit with rxjava i use it for 10 parallel request

Comment: @josh1dev I don't think that's possibles. The API which I'm using gets me one array per request.

Comment: @MohammadSommakia I read about those libraries which you've mentioned and wanted to use them, but for now I really don't have the time to change my whole network layer. If you say that you can do 10 parallel request without any overhead, then I don't think that volley which handles 4 network thread in parallel makes the overhead, Do you think it might be from the files writing?

Comment: if the cause from the file writing as you suggest, in my opinion it depends on hardware specification of your mobile how or maybe you have bad internet connection, but i think putting your request in a for loop is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Constant storage of writing files during a while makes the CPU work so hard. Also in devices with low numbers of threads it will crash.

I recommend you to use less number of threads, just 1 or 2, so you let the CPU do another tasks and avoid a bad perfomance.

**DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 2**